# Google Analytics structure for a Mobile App

Tags: android, google-analytics, mobile-analytics

We have built a B2b Catalog sharing & trading appon native Android & PhoneGap. Does it make sense to look at Firebase Analytics, or Google Analytics good enough?

With Google Analytics, clarity between which should be recorded as ‘Views’ & which as ‘Activity’ is unclear. Eg Catalog view can be View of Catalog screen, or an activity as (Category = catalog, action = open, label = catalog-name, value = catalog-id). Obviously, more information is recorded in an Activity

Proposed architecture for Google Analytics is below:

**1. Screens/Views:** Home, Login Contact Buyer/Approved, Buyer/Pending,
    Buyer/Detail Supplier/Approved, Supplier/Pending, Supplier/Detail
    CatalogPage, Catalogs/My/List, Catalogs/Received/List,
    Catalogs/Detail, Products/Detail Shared/List, Shared/Detail
    Selection/List, Selection/Open, Selection/Create SalesOrder/List,
    SalesOrder/Open, SalesOrder/Edit PurchaseOrder/List,
    PurchaseOrder/Open, PurchaseOrder/Edit Notification/List,
    Notification/Detail [some more..]

**2. Events:**

[image]

The challenge is this - there’s obviously duplication in recording what is happening on the app as a View or Event, and I’m unclear on the best reconciliation for this. I’ve tried to keep Pages / Screens as Views, and the Buttons / Links on them as Actions.

Does this look ok? Any inputs / thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use both Google Analytics and Firebase in your app.  This can help you compare and contrast the implementations and data gathered from your app.

Comment: Using firebase core includes Google Analytics(or Analytics from Firebase).